# Differences between responding with dynamically created XML and XML file

Tags: xml, node.js, vast

So here's a problem I'm busting my head around for the past few days:

I have a nodeJS app that does the following:

```
var VAST = require('vast-xml');
var vast = new VAST();

vast.version = "2.0";

var ad=vast.attachAd({
      id : 1
    , structure : 'wrapper'
    , sequence : 99
    , Error: 'http://error.err'
    , VASTAdTagURI : 'http://demo.tremormedia.com/proddev/vast/vast_inline_linear.xml'
    , AdTitle : 'Common name of the ad'
    , AdSystem : { name: 'Test Ad Server', version : '1.0' }
  });

  response.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(vast.xml()));
  response.setHeader('Connection', 'close');

  response.writeHead( 200, {'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8'} );

  response.end(vast.xml());
```

Here's the URL that invoke the above code:
http://tag.sprtad.com/?ttj=4
The returned XML is:

```
<VAST version="2.0">
<Ad id="1" sequence="99">
  <Wrapper>
  <AdSystem version="1.0">Test Ad Server</AdSystem>
  <VASTAdTagURI>
    <![CDATA[http://demo.tremormedia.com/proddev/vast/vast_inline_linear.xml ]]>
  </VASTAdTagURI>
  <Error>
     <![CDATA[http://error.err ]]>
  </Error>
  <Creatives />
  </Wrapper>
  </Ad>
</VAST>
```

Now, here's a **file** that returns the exact same XML: http://serve.sprtad.com/test.xml

Here's the problem:

I'm using this VAST-Validator to ensure that the XML is valid:
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/vastinspector_dual

Just paste the first URL or the second URL in the VAST tag textbox, and click on 'test ad' button.

Below the video player, there's a log console. 
In the log you'll be able to see that for the first link, it returns an error and for the second link, it works fine!

I cannot pinpoint what's the difference between serving the XML dynamically vs. serving the XML file.

Comment: Unless you changed things since posting this question, the dynamic served file and the static file are very different. Getting them to send down the same XML would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Validator gives a network error for http://tag.sprtad.com/?ttj=4 and the XML includes a single quote inside the VASTAdTagURI node:

'http://vpc.altitude-arena.c...

Did not not test in full detail, but that's hopefully a good hint :-)